# Kodi HDMI-CEC right-click with TV remote without such button

Tags: hdmi, kodi, libreelec

Normally you control Kodi (I'm using LibreELEC) with left-clicks and right-clicks with special buttons on your TV remote through HDMI-CEC. My new Samsung TV has a minimalistic remote that has a left-click button but sadly lacks a button for right-click. How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keymap editor](https://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Keymap_Editor) is your friend

You can easily add any action to some remote control keys (some keys like mute, volume, power etc are not available to be captured by the CEC )

Comment: Friends—How many of us have them!!!

Answer (score 4):

TV remotes usually have colored buttons (red, yellow, green, blue). For Samsung, there's a special button that opens a selection window on the TV where you can select a color. You can map, for instance, the red button to [correspond to a right click](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=227022). Do this by editing the file `/storage/.kodi/userdata/keymaps/remote.xml`. Insert the following code and reboot:

```
<keymap>
  <global>
    <remote>
    <red>contextmenu</red>
    </remote>
  </global>
</keymap>
```